# How to make a space disappear from between the value and percent sign?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

this is a quick one. In one of the emails we are about to send out there is a weid space appearing in between the value pulled in through AMPscript and the % sign.

E.g. %%rate%%%

Result:

7.99 % instead of 7.99%

I checked the data but there is no space in there, it's just the number (e.g. 7.99). Also the same data file it's used for a different email and that one renders properly.

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Vic

Comment: Where are you sending this email from?  What are you using to send this email?

Comment: Sorry, thought my post tag helped categorizing the conversation. I use Exact Target. Thanks for jumping in.

Comment: can you verify that the data doesn't have spaces?

Comment: I should probably look at tags better... I probably should know what Exact Target is before trying to help.

Comment: Did this end up working for you?  If so, make sure you mark the question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this in my account, and the values came back exactly as you would expect. I would suggest using the  `Trim()` function.

```
%%=Trim(rate)=%%&#37;
```

That will produce the correct result. Most likely it's a data issue.

**edit**

To Vic's point below - Concat will work. Best practice would be to also account for any extra white space, you you could also do:

```
%%=Concat(Trim(rate),'%')=%
```

Comment: Also as a side note, its probably a good idea to use the HTML code for a percent sign since perecent signs are used in the AMPscript syntax. I would rewrite Kelly's code as %%=Trim(rate)=%%&#37; -- &#37; is the HTML code for '%'

Comment: Good point - and not a bad practice - edited.

Comment: Thanks Kelly, it seems Concat is doing the same thing. e.g. %%=Concat(rate,'%')=%%